# Max Recursion, how to fix

Tags: python, recursion

My code is stops working. It outputs **maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object**
Here is my code:

```
# First We import time for waiting, random for selecting the 3 numbers, and the 3 globals for use of other functions
import time
import random
import sys
global ca2
global ca1
global ca3
global guesses
global correctNumbers
global correctOrder
guesses = 0


def lose():
    print("You have ", correctNumbers, "Numbers Correct")
    print("And", correctOrder, "Numbers That are correct in order.")
    startLevel1()


def win():
    print("Congratulations!")
    print("It took you", guesses, "guesses to Win.")
    q2 = input()
    if q2 == "yes":
        startGame()


def input():
    # entering numbers
    correctNumbers = 0
    ca1 = 0
    ca2 = 0
    ca3 = 0
    numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
    ca1 = random.choice(numbers)
    ca2 = random.choice(numbers)
    ca3 = random.choice(numbers)
    ifa = [ca1, ca2, ca3]
    correctOrder = 0
    input1 = input()
    input2 = input()
    input3 = input()
    if input1 == ca1: #here we are testinf for input1 of all 3 numbers.
        print("The First Number Is 100% Correct. Number and Order.")
        correctNumbers += 1
        correctOrder += 1
    if input1 == ifa:
        correctNumbers += 1
    if input2 == ca2:  #over here we are doing the same thing but for 2
        print("The Second number Is 100% Correct. Number and Order.")
        correctOrder += 1
        correctNumbers += 1
    if input2 == ifa:
        correctNumbers += 1
    if input3 == ca3:  #same here, but for 3
        print("The Third number Is 100% Correct. Number and Order.")
        correctOrder += 1
        correctNumbers += 1
    if input3 == ifa:
        correctNumbers += 1
    if correctNumbers == 3:
        win()
    else:
        lose()
        guesses += 1


def startLevel1():
    #chooses the numbers
    wait1sec()
    numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
    ca1 = random.choice(numbers)
    ca2 = random.choice(numbers)
    ca3 = random.choice(numbers)
    input()


#The game starts here
def startGame():
    guesses = 0
    print("Welecome To Mastermind!")
    print("How To Play:")
    wait1sec()
    print("1. The Computer will select 3 numbers from 1 to 10, you must guess all 3 numbers in the right order.")
    wait1sec()
    print("2. Each time you guess, the computer will tell you how much numbers did you guess right, and tell you if those numbers were in the correct order.")
    wait1sec()
    print("3.There is no limit to how much guesses you can use.")
    wait1sec()
    print("You win by guessing all the correct numbers in the right order")
    startLevel1()


def wait1sec():
    time.sleep(1)


startGame()
```

I am making a game called mastermind.
i tried using `dict`s but they won't work
can anyone help me, i am just a beginner
thanks.
also i am using pycharm, and python 3.0.
i think it is because of all the if's?
i dont really know

Comment: Have you noticed that your `input` function calls `input` (which is itself). You shouldn't use python reserved functions as your function name. They replaces the reserved function with the newly created ones. Change your function name from `input` to something else.

Comment: thanks, i will try it out